# How does an interface remove dependency from implementation?

Tags: java, oop, interface, architecture, clean-architecture

I am reading Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture book. One of the main points throughout the book is that you should depend on abstractions, not on implementations.

For example, he mentions that the higher layers of the software shouldn't know anything from the lower layers (which I agree). He also points out that when a higher layer needs to communicate with a lower layer, the lower layer must implement an interface that the higher layer uses. For example, if the Use Case layer needs to call the Presenter layer, it should be done through an interface OutputBoundary that is implemented by the Presenter, so the Use Case layer does not depend on the presenter. If you do it without an interface, it is really bad because the Use Case layer is depending on the Presenter layer.

How is that true? If in the future the Presenter layer needs more or different data to be sent by the Use Cases, you not only will have to modify the Presenter, but the OutputBoundary Interface and the Use Cases as well. So no, the Use Cases are never completely independent from the Presenter.

If the Presenter changes the way he presents data just changing the body of the method, then the Use Case layer won't have to change anything. If the Presenter changes the way he presents data by changing the method declaration it won't matter if you have an interface or not, because you will have to modify the method call in the Use Case layer. In none of the two cases the use of an interface really matter.

Is there something that I am missing here? I know the uses of an interface, and I know that if you have or plan to have multiple presenters, then having them to implement a common interface would be the right way to go, but even so I can't see the **independence from lower layers** that he mentions on his books.

Answer (score 0):

> How is that true? If in the future the Presenter layer needs more or
> different data to be sent by the Use Cases, you not only will have to
> modify the Presenter, but the OutputBoundary Interface and the Use
> Cases as well. So no, the Use Cases are never completely independent
> from the Presenter.

If the presenter layer needs more or different data then the use cases layer must change to provide that data.

But, if you decide to make changes in the presentation layer, or replace it for a new technology, but the information is the same, you would not need to modify the Use cases layer.

Same idea with data access, you use interfaces so it depends on application instead of the other way around, and when you need to change the data access to use a different database technology, as long as your data access layer keeps implementing the same interfaces, you don't need to make changes in application.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that Radio is higher level of software, then Battery will be lower level of dependency. In real life, Radio does not have tight coupling to Duracell battery, you can use any battery you want.

Let me show an example in C# (sorry, I do not have installed Java editor,  but code is really simple):

```
class Radio
{
    private IBattery _battery;


    public Radio(IBattery battery)
    {
        _battery = battery;
    }


    public void TurnOn() 
    {
        _battery.GiveEnergy();
    }
}


interface IBattery
{
    void GiveEnergy();
}

class Duracell : IBattery
{
    public void GiveEnergy()
    {
        
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
IBattery battery = new Duracell();
var radio = new Radio(battery);
radio.TurnOn();
```

Your higher level - `Radio` does not depend on implementation of lower level `Battery`.

So you can use any battery you want.

Answer (score 0):

> How is that true? If in the future the Presenter layer needs more or different data to be sent by the Use Cases, you not only will have to modify the Presenter, but the OutputBoundary Interface and the Use Cases as well. So no, the Use Cases are never completely independent from the Presenter.

The answer is yes and no
Yes it is true since all layers pointing **inwards not outwards**
which make the communication between layers based on interfaces/abstraction the application layer as example will implement all the code against the interface and not aware with the implementation of that interface but since the higher layer pointing inward so it will consume the interface of the lower layer then implement it which makes the answer yes

every layer by itself it depend on the one lower so Application depend on Core/Entities
and Infrastructure depend on application but here is the trick in your presentation layer you actually will use DI to point the implementation of every interface to that interface which will make them depend on each others only in the run time

in this image you could see the direction of each layer

[image]

> If the Presenter changes the way he presents data just changing the body of the method , then the Use Case layer won't have to change anything.

yes since the data still the same coming from application layer but if the presentation layer required completely diff  let's say View model then the application layer will have to change the data which might need a change in persistence / infrastructure layer which will lead to change in the interface in application layer which  persistence / infrastructure will need to implement !!!

I Actually recommend you to watch this video for **Jason Taylor**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dK4Yb6-LxAk

Let me know if you have any questions